# Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable postgress

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, typeorm

```
 @Query(() => Post, { nullable: true })
  async post(
    @Arg("id", () => Int) id: number
  ): Promise<Post | undefined | null> {
    return await Post.findOne({ id });
  }
```

I have this query which run fine and return the required output. But when i convert this to postgres sql it is not showing error.

```
@Query(() => Post, { nullable: true })
  async post(
    @Arg("id", () => Int) id: number
  ): Promise<Post | undefined | null> {
    
    const posts = await getConnection().query(
      `
          SELECT * FROM post where id = 2
          
        `
    );

    return posts
  }
```

It throw error `Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable` 
[image]

I am new to postgres. Whats the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the first example TypeORM will return either one post or null. In the second example, it will return an array that either contains something or not. I suggest you set a limit to your query

`SELECT * FROM post where id = 2 limit 1`

and return the first element in the resulting array (return posts[0]).